# Laravel Live Search Box

Tags: javascript, php, search

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I have an array of objects that presents data onto a blade template. My objective now is to create a live search box to filter the data. Here is an example of my data:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#196 (6) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["id_customer"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["date_add"]=> string(19) "2016-09-26 16:31:18" 
    ["payment"]=> string(39) "Pagamentos por Transferência Bancária" 
    ["total_paid"]=> string(9) "56.580000" 
    ["reference"]=> string(9) "OFBDWERLL" 
} 
[1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#194 (6) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["id_customer"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["date_add"]=> string(19) "2016-09-26 16:37:59" 
    ["payment"]=> string(39) "Pagamentos por Transferência Bancária" 
    ["total_paid"]=> string(9) "40.590000" 
    ["reference"]=> string(9) "CAYWFSRCA" 
} 
}
```

An example of the search box would be, if I typed in id_customer, it would show me every piece of data that include the id_customer key.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: you should use jquery, angularjs or other javascript framework  to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

In your template you will need to use AJAX that will respond when a user types into a search box.  The ajax will call a php function that performs searches on the fly, passing back the results to the ajax, which then in turn shoves the results into your html.

There are a lot of tutorials online for creating an ajax live search box that you can probably use to help you along further.